# Execution of python script success/fail based on condition

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a `python` script that I will be executing using `Pyspark`. The `python` file is like below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.sql("select id, name, start_date from testing.user_123")

hivedb='test'
table='abc_123'

# Register the Data Frame as a TempTable
df.registerTempTable('mytempTable')

# Create Table in Hive using the temptable
status = 'success'
try:
  sqlContext.sql("create table {}.`{}` as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))
except:
   status = 'fail'

sc.stop()
```

I am getting the desired results. Now when I execute this `python` file using `spark -submit` in `shell script` I am getting the status as `success` all the time.

I want the `Python script execution as failed if the status message is fail` and `success if the status is success`

What do I need to change in my script in order to get the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add an assert statement at the end of your python script. This will fail the python script if the status variable value is not 'success'.

```
assert status == 'success', 'status should be success'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `hivedb` and `table` are both hardcoded, and `mytempTable` already exists, `"create table {}.`{}`as select * from mytempTable"` will always succeed, it'll just create an empty table if it doesn't find any values. You need a different conditional to check against; maybe the length of your `select` query?

Answer (score 0):

try adding sys.exit(1) in your try block

```
try:
    sqlContext.sql("create table {}.`{}` as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))
except:
    status = 'fail'
    sys.exit(1)
```